# Display topic at top of list if has new reply

Tags: codeigniter

I have a list of my topics by default it will get the topics where the reply_id is 0 And then arrange them by there date_created.

How every if there is a reply to one of the topics then that topic should go to the top of the list.

> **Question** How can I make sure if there is a new reply to a topic then that topic will go to list.

Currently my var dump as you can see have two items how ever the 2nd array item should be at top because it has a new last post time()

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => How to
            [author] => demo
            [author_post_time] => Tue Jun 13 , 2017 19:43:01 pm
            [last_post_by] => demo
            [latest_post_time] => Tue Jun 13 , 2017 19:43:01 pm
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => How to install codeigniter
            [author] => admin
            [author_post_time] => Sat Jun 10 , 2017 23:26:48 pm
            [last_post_by] => demo
            [latest_post_time] => Tue Jun 13 , 2017 20:48:00 pm
        )

)
```

Image of database[image]

Model

```
<?php

class Topic_model extends CI_Model 
{
    public function get_active_topics($fid) 
    {
        $data = array();

        $this->db->select('t.*, u.username');
        $this->db->from('topics t');
        $this->db->join('user u', 'u.user_id = t.user_id');
        $this->db->where('t.reply_id', '0');
        $this->db->order_by('t.date_created', 'desc');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $topic_result) 
        {
            $reply = $this->get_reply($topic_result['topic_id']);

            // This $date1 just for display only as shown on image
            $date1 = date('D M d', $topic_result['date_created']) . ' , ' . date('Y H:i:s a', $topic_result['date_created']);

            // This $date2 just for display only as shown on image
            $date2 = date('D M d', $reply['date_created']) . ' , ' . date('Y H:i:s a', $reply['date_created']);

            $data[] = array(
                'title' => $topic_result['title'],
                'author' => $topic_result['username'],
                'author_post_time' => $date1,
                'last_post_by' => isset($reply['username']) ? $reply['username'] :  $topic_result['username'],
                'latest_post_time' => ($reply['reply_id'] > 0) ? $date2 : $date1, 
            );

        }

        return $data;
    }

    public function get_reply($reply_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('t.*, u.username');
        $this->db->from('topics t');
        $this->db->join('user u', 'u.user_id = t.user_id');
        $this->db->where('t.reply_id', $reply_id);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();


        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row_array();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have one or two tables for topics and replies?

Comment: @Tpojka just the one.

Comment: Because this is two tables job. Similar to blog articles and comments with one to many relation between.

Comment: @Tpojka I tried with two tables had no luck so went back to one.

Comment: Study normal forms in DB (tables) design. Especially pay attention on [3rd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) one. It should be done logically. If you don't respect some key points of how things need to be done, you are going into issues deeper and deeper and code is becoming hard or impossible to maintain. You need `topics` table with all attributes of topic. Excluding anything that is related to replies. With that, you need `replies` table with all attributes reply needs and with `topic_id` as foreign key. You should go from that point IMHO.

Comment: @Tpojka I went back to the two table way as I tried it first one of the answers suggested to try something like this `$this->db->order_by('r.date_created DESC, t.date_created DESC');` it worked now.

Comment: I didn't understand if you are using one table or two tables design. I don't see that accepted answer include replies table nor replies create date, but if that floats your boat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use below mentioned line, I hope this will fix your issue.

Change From

```
$this->db->order_by('t.date_created', 'desc');
```

TO

```
$this->db->order_by('t.reply_id DESC, t.date_created DESC');
```

Comment: Vote up from me. I just tried going back to the two table way and tried your way `$this->db->order_by('r.date_created DESC, t.date_created DESC');` this way seem to work now thanks for tip

Comment: @wolfgang1983, Glad to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try ordering your table first by date2 and if that doesnt exist (no reply) then date1. You seem to have it implemented already, you're just ordering by date created on the post.

Comment: $date1 and $date2 are just for the display as you can see in the image at bottom

Comment: sorry, when I said date1 and date2 I meant change this line '$this->db->order_by('t.date_created', 'desc');' to order by most recent reply instead if reply_id is not 0 for any of the topics